# Create a complete binary tree and do level order traversal on it

Tags: c++, tree, breadth-first-search

How can I optimize this code?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<queue>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *left,*right;
};

Node *createNode(int data){
    Node *node=new Node;
    node->left=NULL;
    node->right=NULL;
    node->data=data;
    return node;
}

Node buildTree(Node *newNode,queue<Node *>&q){
    Node *f=q.front();
    if(f->left && f->right) {q.pop();f=q.front();}
    if(!f->left) f->left=newNode;
    else if(!f->right) f->right=newNode;
    q.push(newNode);
}


void levelOrder(Node *root){
    queue<Node*>q;
    if(root){
        q.push(root);
        while(!q.empty()){
            Node *d =q.front();
            q.pop();
            cout<<d->data<<" ";
            if(d->left) q.push(d->left);
            if(d->right) q.push(d->right);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    Node *root=createNode(10);
    queue<Node *>q;
    q.push(root);
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        buildTree(createNode(i),q);
    }
    levelOrder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

#### `using namespace std;`

> ```
> using namespace std;
> ```

[Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/6660678)

The particular problem I have with it here is that it obscures that you are using `std::queue` and not some custom class.

Note that this can also cause problems if you later convert it to header file, which would be natural for a general use data structure.

#### Don't go the long way around

> ```
> Node *createNode(int data){
>     Node *node=new Node;
>     node->left=NULL;
>     node->right=NULL;
>     node->data=data;
>     return node;
> }
> ```

Rather than create a function for this, consider just creating a constructor for `struct Node`.

```
Node::Node(int datum) {
    this->datum = datum;
    left = NULL;
    right = NULL;
}
```

Note that `datum` is the singular form of `data`, so I changed the field in `Node` to `datum` as it only holds one piece.

> ```
>         buildTree(createNode(i),q);
> ```

could become

```
        buildTree(new Node(i), q);
```

This calls a constructor directly rather than creating a function just to call the default constructor and set the data.

#### Why wait?

> ```
>     if(f->left && f->right) {q.pop();f=q.front();}
>     if(!f->left) f->left=newNode;
>     else if(!f->right) f->right=newNode;
> ```

This could be

```
    if (f->left) {
        f->right = newNode;
        q.pop();
    } else {
        f->left = newNode;
    }
```

This works because you know that something is only in the queue until both its children are added.  Then it is removed.  So you don't need to check for the both children full case if you only ever add to the tree with this method.

I changed the order because I find it easier to read positive conditions with `else` blocks.  An `else` is essentially the negation of the `if`.  This way we aren't negating a negative.

What if something else adds to the tree?  That would be problematic.  Of course, that was already true.  Something else adding to the tree would interfere with the order that you use the queue to enforce.

Removals are also problematic with either implementation.

This is why `Node` would normally be a hidden data type, not exposed to callers.  Then you could be sure that only your tree class would be able to access it.

#### Don't make data structures that you don't use

> ```
>     queue<Node*>q;
>     if(root){
> ```

If you do this in the other order, you can save the overhead of creating the `std::queue`.

```
    if (root) {
        queue<Node*> q;
```

or even

```
    if (!root) {
        return;
    }

    queue<Node*> q;
```

Which also reduces the indent.

#### Efficiency

The biggest problem with efficiency that I see is that this doesn't seem to be a tree in any meaningful sense.  Sure, the data structure behind it is a tree, but the operations aren't.  You `buildTree` in insertion order.  Then you `levelOrder` to read back the tree in insertion order.  If you only wanted to do that, then a `std::vector` would be a much more efficient data structure.  You wouldn't need the `std::queue` to manage the insertions nor reading them back.

> ```
>     Node *root=createNode(10);
>     queue<Node *>q;
>     q.push(root);
>     for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
>         buildTree(createNode(i),q);
>     }
>     levelOrder(root);
> ```

would become

```
    std::vector<int> data;
    data.push_back(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        data.push_back(i);
    }

    for (auto datum : data) {
        std::cout << datum << " ";
    }
```

Isn't that simpler?  No new functions required.  Also, rather than using a pointer-based data structure *and* a queue, this just uses one array-based data structure.  You could also use a `std::queue` instead of a `std::vector`.

#### Encapsulation

This is also encapsulated better.  Instead of having to create a tree structure and a queue in order to call `buildTree`, this simply calls `push_back` and lets `std::vector` handle the details internally.  Consider the following interface

```
class InsertionOrderTree {
    struct Node {
        int datum;
        Node *left;
        Node *right;
    };

    Node *root;
    std::queue<int> q;

    public:
    InsertionOrderTree();
    build(int datum);
    traverse();
};

InsertionOrderTree::InsertionOrderTree() {
    root = NULL;
}
```

This hides the implementation detail of using a queue from any callers.  Callers shouldn't have to know how you do things, just what you promise to do.  They certainly should not have to create a specific data structure just to help you do whatever it is that you are doing.  You should create your own data structures if you need them.

Note that the implementations of `build` and `traverse` would change from your original versions.  In particular, `build` needs to handle a `NULL` `root`.

#### Unsolicited advice

This is a bad use case for a tree though.  You should probably either find a different use case that better fits a tree (if you just want to implement a tree) or use a different data structure (if this is really the problem that you need to solve).

Answer (score 2):

I am still learning myself, but I will only give you advice that I have been given recently.

Instead of using the new operator try researching smart pointers, [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr),  it takes away the pain of handling the memory manually, especially if you are coming for languages like Java, C# or PHP(Like me), where you are not used to memory management.

Answer (score 1):

I see some things that may help you improve your code.

### Make sure all paths return a value

The `buildTree` routine claims to return a `Node` but doesn't.  Either change the function signature to `void` or modify the code to actually return a `Node`.

### Don't abuse `using namespace std`

Putting `using namespace std` at the top of every program is [a bad habit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) that you'd do well to avoid.

### Use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`

Modern C++ uses `nullptr` rather than `NULL`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282295/what-exactly-is-nullptr/1283623#1283623) for why and how it's useful.

### Use object orientation

Because you're writing in C++, it would make sense to have methods that operate on a class such as `Node` be member functions rather than separate functions.  In addition, it allows the *implementation* to be separate from the *interface*.  This allows others to use your code without needing to know or care about the details of how it's implemented.  An example is that the `buildTree()` function very peculiarly requires a `std::queue` as a passed value.  Better would be to have a `Tree` object and then have a `levelOrder` traversal member fuction.

### Use a constructor rather than a standalone function

The `createNode` function would be better expressed as `Node` constructor.

```
struct Node {
    Node(int thedata) 
        : data{thedata}, left{nullptr}, right{nullptr}
    {}
    int data;
    Node *left, *right;
};
```

Now instead of using `createNode`, you can simply do this:

```
Node *root = new Node(10);
```

### Use more whitespace

Instead of writing a line like this:

```
if(f->left && f->right) {q.pop();f=q.front();}
```

use a bit more whitespace and write it like this:

```
if (f->left && f->right) {
    q.pop();
    f = q.front();
}
```

### Don't leak memory

Unless there is a corresponding `delete` for every `new` in your program, it will leak memory.  One simple way to do this with the existing code would be to do a post-order traversal like this:

```
void delTree(Node *root) {
    if (root) {
        delTree(root->left);
        delTree(root->right);
        delete root;
        root = nullptr;
    }
}
```

### Consider an alternative data structure

Depending on how you're going to be using these binary trees, an alternative structure would be to use an array.  The canonical way to do this would be to store the root at index 1.  Then the left and right children of the root would be at index 2 and index 3 respectively.  Generally, then for any given node stored at index \$n\$, its left and right children are at index \$2n\$ and \$2n+1\$ respectively.  This makes an level traversal extremely simple since all that's then needed is to step through the array.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.